# Difference Between べんきょう する and べんきょうを する

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between べんきょう する and べんきょうを する?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can we optionally include (or exclude) an を particle in between the noun of the する-verb and the する itself?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/can-we-optionally-include-or-exclude-an-%e3%82%92-particle-in-between-the-noun-of-the)

Comment: @Flaw: Thanks for pointing. That is really nice. I didn't find it when I was posting my question.

Comment: I'm not a native, but to me the difference feels to me rather like the difference between saying "to study" vs "to do (some) studying" in English...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

勉強{べんきょう}する is one verb. 勉強をする is a phrase.

They don't seem to have any difference in meaning, but the usage may differ.

For 勉強する, an object can be added:

> 日本語{にほんご}を勉強する learn Japanese 
>  <s>日本語を勉強をする</s>  is wrong

For 勉強をする, adjectives (or words or phrases that can be used as adjectives) can be used before 勉強:

> しばらく医者{いしゃ}になるための勉強をする study for a while to become a doctor

While 勉強する cannot be used in this way.

Comment: So could you say 日本語の勉強をする?

Comment: @atlantiza Yes. That would be more straightforwardly contrasted with `日本語を勉強する`.