# Can any 名詞をする be shorten as 名詞する?

Tags: grammar

Can any 名詞をする be shorten as 名詞する ? Is there any exception for this?

For example,

- 勉強をする can be shorten as 勉強する
- テニスをする　can be shorten as テニスする

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4006/5010

Comment: 質問わかりにくっ！カッコとか使おうよ。最後の二行を読むまで、質問の意味、不明だった。