# いろいろ質問する versus いろいろな質問する

Tags: grammar

Most people use いろいろ質問する. But if I analyze it, いろいろ is な形容詞.

So I think it should be いろいろな質問する. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- いろいろ can be used as a standalone adverb. (e.g. 色々話す, 色々ある, ...)
- 質問する without を is a *verb*, and it cannot be directly modified by the dictionary form of an adjective. (See [this similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4007/5010) on 勉強する/勉強をする)

Thus, these three phrases are all natural:

- いろいろな質問をする
- いろいろ質問をする
- いろいろ質問する

But this phrase is non-standard:

- いろいろな質問する

Comment: What is the English translation for いろいろ質問する? Is it "to 
question variously" ?

Comment: All of these usually mean "ask various questions," but do not mean "ask a question in various ways."

Answer (score 2):

いろいろ can also be considered an adverb.

If you are describing the **types** of questions, いろいろな質問 would be correct. But in the case of いろいろ質問する, you are talking about the **action** of asking different things, and thus doesn't require な.