# How does の連絡しな work in じゃあ、私早退の子の連絡しなきゃいけないから?

Tags: particle-の

じゃあ私早退の子の連絡しなきゃいけないから

The teacher says this at the beginning of the scene, with no further context

I'm confused about the use of 早退の子の連絡 here. Specifically I don't see how の連絡しな works?

Comment: Do you know how to understand しなきゃいけない?  This is standard grammatical construction.  If you don't recognize it, do you recognize しなければいけない?  This later is the uncontracted form of the former.

Comment: I do, but I don't understand how it's acting with 私早退の子の連絡?
"I must do kid who leaves early communication"?

Comment: If your question is solved, please [check the most helpful answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/719822).

Answer (score 3):

早退の子の連絡 refers to informing the student who left early about tomorrow's homework or textbooks they need to bring. It would have been clearer to say 早退した子への連絡 instead, but since this is a common practice at least in Japanese schools, a brief expression like this is sufficient to convey the meaning.

With this in mind, the overall structure of the expression is exactly the same as [部屋の掃除(を)する](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26120/5010) or [英語の勉強(を)する](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4006/5010).

> じゃあ私早退の子の連絡しなきゃいけないから。
> = じゃあ私は、早退した子**への**連絡**を**しなきゃいけないから。
> = じゃあ私は、早退した子**に**連絡(を)しなきゃいけないから。
>
> I have to call/contact a student who left early.

Comment: Or, the teacher was responsible for reporting when there is a child who returned early to the schoolmaster or someone administrating the classroom.  じゃあ私は'早退の子の（ことを）連絡しなきゃいけないから。'