# Usage of 如き, 如し, 如く

Tags: grammar, word-choice, homonyms

如き【ごとき】, 如し【ごとし】, 如く【ごとく】 all mean "like/as if/the same as". Is there a certain way they can be used or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are all different forms of the helping verb ごとし.

They are used differently this way:

- 如し ⇒ のようだ (used as a verb)
- 如く ⇒ のように、のようで (used like an adverb)
- 如き ⇒ のような (used as an adjective)

> - 目差しは炎**の如し**　⇒　目差しは炎**のようだ**
>     (his) gaze was as a flaming fire
> - 海**の如く**広い草原を渡る　⇒　海の**ように**広い草原を渡る
>     (we) cross a plain wide as the sea
> - 馬**の如き**速さで走る　⇒　馬**のような**速さで走る
>     to run with the speed of a horse

如く is the 連用形 of 如し:

- 眼差しは炎の**如く**、相手‌​を捕えていた。

如き is the 連体形 of 如し:

- 炎の**如き眼差し**で、攻撃の準備をしていた。

Comment: Heh.. I've always thought that 如き is just 連体形 and the 連用形 of 如し is just 如く...  `如き ... can also be used as the 連用形 of 如し` <- Do you have a source? 目差しは炎の如**き**、攻撃の準備していた sounds incorrect to me, but is it just me?

Comment: 「目差し」って聞いたことないのですが。「目つき」や「眼光」なら使いますが。 あと「攻撃の準備する」も[変です](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4007/5010).

Comment: @naruto あっ、「[日]{ひ}差し」って読んでたｗ

Comment: Sounded OK to me, maybe a bit like 古文 though. http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A6%82%E3%81%8D Shows some potentially conflicting information about 如き, but both entries show that it is a 連用形

Comment: 如き as a 連用形 is [如]{し}き, not [如]{ごと}き... It's the 連用形 of the verb [如]{し}く, as in [如]{し}きて

Comment: あ、目差しって「眼差し（まなざし）」のことですか？　うちのIMEでは変換できませんが某辞書には載ってるようです。

Comment: @naruto Can you suggest a better sentence for an example at the end?

Comment: @chocolate 大辞線 says that ごとき is the 連用形 of ごとし. Do you have another source that says something else?

Comment: 今ある文を直すなら「眼差しは炎のごとく、攻撃の準備**を**していた。」ですかね・・「炎のごとき眼差しで、攻撃の準備をしていた/攻撃を準備していた」のほうがいいかも？連体形を使うことになるけど・・

Comment: `大辞線 says that ごとき is the 連用形 of ごとし` -> Do you mean [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A6%82%E3%81%8D-503015)? I can't see it saying that. I can only see 「ごとき【▽如き】

《比況の助動詞「ごとし」の連**体**形》」 there

Comment: @chocolate & naruto 編集しました。如何ですか？

Comment: @chocolate Yes, デジタル大辞線 is the one I meant.

Comment: あらまぁ。。。ちがうよね　連体形だ！

Comment: @sazarando  「眼差しは炎の如く、攻撃の準備をしていた」だと主語が「眼差し」なので、目そのものが攻撃しようとしているように見えるのが少し気持ち悪いです。「眼差しは炎の如く相手を捕えていた」なら全く構わないと思います。

Answer (score 5):

- ～(の)如し is used as a predicate. (sounds archaic rather than simply literary)
- ～(の)如き modifies a noun (i.e., adjectivally).
- ～(の)如く modifies a verb (i.e., adverbially).

> その動きは蝶の如し。  His movement is like a butterfly.
>   光陰矢の如し。 Time flies. (lit. "Days and nights are like arrows.")
>   蝶の如き動きを見せた。 He showed a butterfly-like movement.
>   蝶の如く動いた。 He moved like a butterfly.