# Connecting Sino-Japanese verbs

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntax

As a rule the Japanese verbs are connected by ~たり pattern.
For example:

> 出社【しゅっしゃ】し**たり**退社【たいしゃ】**したりする**。

But is it grammatically correct, when I connect these two verbs by 及び【および】?
For example:

> 出社**及び**退社する。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

出社及び退社する makes perfect sense, but I think 出社および退社**を**する (using を) is the safer choice when making a written sentence. It's because so-called suru-verbs work basically as *verbs*, whereas および is to connect two *nouns*. Likewise, 掃除や洗濯した is not good in written Japanese, and you usually have to write 掃除や洗濯**を**した. In spoken Japanese, particles are omitted more often, so 掃除や洗濯した tend to be tolerated.

The usage is a bit different between Xする and Xをする. See: [Difference Between べんきょう する and べんきょうを する](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4006/5010)

In this case, you can also simply write 出退社 (e.g. 出退社する, 出退社の時間).