# Why does the following sentence contain など?

Tags: grammar

If you have read Japanese Wikipedia articles such as [this one](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8F%E3%83%8E%E4%B8%80), you will have come across sentences like the following.

> この項目を加筆・訂正**など**してくださる協力者を求めています

My translation of the sentence goes like this:

> We are looking for collaborators who would be so kind as to improve and correct this item.

What stumps me about the sentence is that it contains など. My research indicates that など is attached to nouns. If I try to make a literal translation, I will get something like this.

> We are looking for collaborators who would be so kind as to make improvements, corrections and so on for this item.

If I didn't add “for”, the sentence would be grammatically incorrect in English. Maybe I'm overthinking this, but does the sentence really need など in it?

Comment: The sentence doesn't "need" it, but it gives the nuance that the two aforementioned things are just two of the many things you can contribute to Wikipedia site/articles... "things like", "etc", "and so on" like you mentioned are good ways of looking at it imo. Maybe you want more of a confirmation than an actual explanation?

Comment: I agree with Felipe. など (or 等) is mostly unnecessary when translated into English but it's there in the original Japanese in case there may be other work needed than 加筆 and/or 訂正 only.

Answer (score 3):

など can attach to all of the following:

- A noun

  > 本などを読む
- Dictionary form of a (non-suru) verb

  > 本を読むなどする

  <sup>(This is slightly stilted; とか and たり/だり are more common in informal settings)</sup>
- A suru-verb

  > 読書など(を)する

  <sup>(を is optional even in formal sentences)</sup>

All suru-verbs are basically also nouns, and など can even attach to ordinary verbs, so I think the last item is not surprising.

By the way, the sentence can be rephrased to この項目**の**加筆・訂正など**を**してくださる協力者を求めています, which is a bit closer to your "literal" English translation ([this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4006/5010) is related).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I guess I needed to understand what parts you can attach など to. So, would a more accurate translation of the sentence be something like, “We are looking for collaborators who would be so kind as to improve this item, correct this item and so on.”

Comment: あと、述語というか節全体にもつきますよね。「変色している、異物が混入しているなどありましたら交換いたします」