# Is になるなどを行う in this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax

> 政党の派閥の場合、その政党で統一されているもの以外の政策や主張に共通点のある者同志が集まって、意見の集約と統一された政策の形成を図り、政策の実現に向けての活動として、その政党の執行部を担当もしくは目標とし、政党の運営の基本単位**になるなどを行う**組織または団体

How come a verb comes before and after を here ?

Answer (score 2):

など [can directly follow a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74001/5010) and form something like a suru-verb. For example, 食べるなどを行う and 食べるなどする are both correct and mean "do things such as eating". 政党の運営の基本単位になるなどを行う組織 means "an organization that, among other things, serves as the basic unit for managing a political party."

That said, 行う is a verb meaning "perform; carry out", and it's used with a task with a beginning and an end. 基本単位になることを行う sounds awkward to me. 政党の運営の基本単位になるなどする組織 would have been better.

(I got an impression that the original sentence is not very organized. 政党の執行部を担当もしくは目標とする in the middle makes little sense to me...)

Comment: Their has been an edit to the article and the definition became その政党の執行部を担当もしくは目標とし、政党の交流におけるコミュニケーションの場となる組織または団体を指す。

Comment: @user50156 It looks better (grammatically), but still 執行部を目標とする doesn't make sense as the definition of 派閥 to me.