# 電話する or 電話をする to form the verb

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to know if there is any difference between 電話する and 電話をする, if they mean the same, or if 電話をする doesn't even exist.

I ask this because in an exercise in my book it says to use をする with 電話 to form the verb, but on the online dictionary I usually check it says it's 電話する, without を.

Dictionary link: http://tangorin.com/general/%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1

Comment: Have you seen these questions: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/difference-between-%e3%81%b9%e3%82%93%e3%81%8d%e3%82%87%e3%81%86-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-and-%e3%81%b9%e3%82%93%e3%81%8d%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%82%92-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/can-we-optionally-include-or-exclude-an-%e3%82%92-particle-in-between-the-noun-of-the ?

Comment: By all means, learn to use 「電話をする」 first, then learn to drop the particle in informal convo.  If you learned to use 「電話する」 first, you might not know if anything is being omitted.

Answer (score 1):

> I ask this because in an exercise in my book it says to use をする with 電話 to form the verb, but on the online dictionary I usually check it says it's 電話する, without を.

Similar to [fefe's answer on a closely related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4007/29), 電話をする is really a phrase, not a "word", so it probably wouldn't show up in a dictionary as a unit.

In this case, it might be fair to say that the meanings are the same. In some ways it can be compared to "I'll give X a call" vs "I'll call X". There are corner cases where the former could sound "odd", but for all practical purposes they mean the same thing.

One technical note: を shouldn't be used with 電話をする to indicate the topic of the phone call, whereas it can be used with 電話する... following a more general rule about not having more than one を in a clause.

Answer (score -2):

been in japan for almost 5 years already and have passed n5 and n4, from my conversations and from what i have heard, 電話する is used and the only time i have heard of 電話をする is in the classroom.  having said this, it is important to know the usage of を and how it is used/not used in the real world.

Comment: One can most definitely hear 電話をします in real conversation. Credentials don't mean much really, but flashing around a JLPT N4 is not much of a credential...