# Why is using the particle 'wo' now seemingly optional?

Tags: particles

Why is using wo, now seemingly optional? Now I tend to only see noun suru opposed to noun wo suru/shimasu. What are the implications/ connotations of using or not using wo? Are there times where you have to use it or is it now down to formality?

(sorry my Japanese keyboard isn't working)

Comment: Related or duplicate:  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1532/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4006/9831

Comment: Can you please give some specific examples? It's not clear whether you're talking about する verbs such as 勉強する or using する with an "unaffiliated" noun like 何かをする. You're right that it's common to drop the を in casual conversation in the second case, but in writing and more formal speech it's required. In the case of する verbs, it's often ungrammatical to *include* the を. For example, 日本語を勉強する is correct but 日本語を勉強をする is not.

Comment: ( sorry my Japanese keyboard isn't working) for example, we learnt to get married is kekkon wo shimasu, but now we would just say kekkon shimasu both seemingly interchangeable. Also with nanika wo suru, is it not also correct to say nanisuru?

Comment: ^ They are not always interchangeable. You can say 幸せな結婚**を**する but not 幸せな結婚する, and 特別な何か**を**する but not 特別な何かする, since 結婚 and 何か in 結婚をする/何かをする are nouns and the objects for the verb する.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The を particle is often left out of casual conversations, in fact casual conversations in general enjoy the luxury of not having to use as many particles as polite/formal speech.

> Example: 日本語を話す。  ー＞ 日本語話す。

Even in polite/formal speech its common to see 私は日本語話します。