# noun + を + nounする vs noun の noun を する

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

Are both of these formats interchangeable?:

noun の noun を する

noun + を + noun する

For example:
*I'm going to practice the piano on Monday*

> 月曜日に**ピアノの練習をする**つもりです
>
> (noun の noun を する)

> 月曜日に**ピアノを練習する**つもりです
>
> (noun + を + nounする)

Do both of these sentences work and make sentence? Do they mean the exact same or do they emphasise words differently?

This question is about all uses of both "する formats".

Comment: するます makes no sense. Did you mean するつもりです or します?

Comment: Whoops, yes you are right

Comment: Does this Q&A help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/can-we-optionally-include-or-exclude-an-%e3%82%92-particle-in-between-the-noun-of-the

Comment: I don't think it quite does, I am more asking about the の particle rather than を.

Answer (score 2):

I think the general answer to your question is "yes" (assuming the second "noun" is a する-verb noun), but I do think the flavor/meaning of the phrase changes. I expect the differences are roughly equivalent to English "I'm going to do some piano practice now" vs "I'm going to practice piano now".

In general I'd expect をする to have the connotation of "doing X", whereas with suru-verb noun + する (no を), you can more readily think of the noun+する as a single verb/word in its own right, at least in terms of translation.