# Is this sentence correct? 時間をゲームをするために過ごす (spend your time in order to play games)

Tags: grammar

1. I'm currently battling myself to know if this sentence is correct or not, 時間をゲームするために過ごす seems correct to me but adding a を doesn't. If it isn't correct please paraphrase it
2. Is there even a difference with adding a を to a 漢語名詞 ?

Comment: Refer to [Can we optionally include (or exclude) an を particle in between the noun of the する-verb and the する itself?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1532/78) for your 2nd question.

Comment: @istrasci you just solved my question, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use 過ごす in this context; I would prefer ゲームに時間を費【つい】やす, ゲームに時間を使う, ゲームするのに時間をかける etc.

「有意義な時間を過ごす」「楽しい時間を過ごす」「家族と時間を過ごす」are perfectly fine, but somehow I find 時間をゲームするために過ごす or 時間をゲームに過ごす extremely unnatural or even at the verge of being ungrammatical.

Comment: +1: I was thinking the same and also wondering if *spend time **in order to** play games* in the title was natural in English. I decided that that was what OP wanted to say, like playing games is the purpose of spending your time doing whatever you do.